# Need help processing forms very basic

Tags: php, html, forms

Not sure what the heck I am doing wrong here as I am trying to learn how to process forms and followed this tutorial(http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) to a T and still couldn't get it to work. You'll see some minor differences, but I have been trying to get this working for the last hour and have added different things to try and fix it.

Here is my first file:

```
    <html>
<body>

<form action="data.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name: <input type="text" name="test"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my data.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    $name = $_POST['test']; }

?>


Welcome <?php echo $name; ?><br>
```

I added a var_dump($Globals)

```
  'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' => string 'test=asdf' (length=9)
  '_GET' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '_POST' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '_COOKIE' => 
    array (size=1)
      'Phpstorm-67f10f2' => string '2e6a5757-50fb-4c36-8bd7-0fe98e66892d' (length=36)
  '_FILES' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '_ENV' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '_REQUEST' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '_SERVER' => 
    array (size=78)
```

I am baffled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: are you actually inputting a name? it's better to use `!empty()` instead of `isset()` btw

Comment: Fair question.  Yes, I am inputting text into the form.

Comment: i test your codes and its working fine.

Comment: unfortunately not for me.  However, I have gotten it to work by using GET/$_GET as well as GET/$_REQUEST.  It is only the POST method that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The variable's only set to the `$_POST` value if it exists but you're asking PHP to display it under all circumstances regardless.

Place the `echo` command in the `if` statement along with the other bit of code.

Comment: I added an echo into the if statement and moved  the "welcome.." into it as well.  I now get no error but nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    echo 'Welcome ' . $_POST['test'] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax help.  Still not echoing anything.  If I drop a var_dump($_post) i get a null value

Answer (score 0):

your form is correct.. just write `print_r($_POST)` to see what all data is carried in the post request... and for getting value of test write

```
$name=$_POST["test"];
echo $name;
```

Comment: For some reason it is not working on my end!  However, I changed everything to GET and it works just fine.  I am 100% confused since it looks like everything is correct, but it just doesn't like the POST method.

Comment: The POST request encapsulates your data from client side and sends it to server side while the GET request appends your data to url and sends it to server side... Both have different purposes.. POST is used for larger data while GET is used for smaller data. @Matt

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with the differences and know that I do not want to use the _GET unless I absolutely have to.  However, based on my situation would you say something is wrong with my WAMP server configuration?

Comment: try to get errors by pasting these commands in your php on first line. error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: I have edited the main question to show the file at this point.

Comment: This must mean it is not a syntax error, but something wrong with my server configuration on WAMP.  However, it was setup as default so I am a  bit frustrated that it wouldn't work with this right out of the gate.  I guess I'l continue to search.

Comment: and I would be glad if i get the answer correct &or vote up from you. @Matt

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem myself by looking through a variety of different posts relating to "$_GET but $_POST doesn't.

There were two things I changed.

First, I was using wamp and my /root folder was not in the /www but rather wamp/root/index.php.

I also added an interpreter in phpstorm by going to FILE|Settings|Build, Exe...|Deployment  and added a local interpreter direction to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12.

Not sure which one solved the issue, but it now works.